# Yacc/Jay grammar file for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, .net, parsing, compiler-construction, yacc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find a yacc gammar for ECMAscript/Actionscript/Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421324/where-can-i-find-a-yacc-gammar-for-ecmascript-actionscript-javascript)

I'm trying to find a grammar file for JavaScript for [Yacc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc) (preferably for Jay, but since [Jay](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/projects/lp/doc/jay/package-summary.html) is a Yacc clone I should be fine, since I need to implement it on .NET).

Answer (score 2):

I think you would have to build it yourself, but there are hints along the way.

The complete JavaScript grammar should be available somewhere; a quick search showed me a [JavaScript LL(1) Grammar](http://hepunx.rl.ac.uk/~adye/jsspec11/llr.htm).  (There's also a BNF schema for JavaScript at [RPA Toolkit: Parse JavaScript](http://www.rpatk.net/web/en/parsejavascript.php).)

Since you're asking only about a parser, I'm going to assume you already have a lexer.

Turning that grammar into a Yacc file really doesn't look so terrible.  As an example, there is a [C grammar for Yacc](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html).

Comment: Have you actually *done* this? Building a *working* parser is harder than it looks for a real language.  People seem to think that it is easy to slap together a grammar and off you go.  Good luck with that.  (Yes, I have done this, for several full languages).

Answer (score 0):

Why not give antlr a go - it looks like it has a grammar made for ecmascript:

http://www.antlr.org/grammar/list

Antlr apparently got a C# runtime as well, even though I have only used it from Java.

Answer (score 0):

Do you realy need to implement it from scratch ? Some libraries like [Jint](http://jint.codeplex.com/) would do the same job, faster and more secure. Jint is a javascript interpreter in .NET - got my own approval.

Answer (score 0):

I write my parsers with COCO/R for C# http://ssw.jku.at/coco/ because it just works with no configuration need. But, It is not source-level compatible with Yacc, Flex, Bison, etc. However, its syntax is simpler. Moreover COCO/R supports a few .NET languages different from C#.
ANTLR works for C# has more features but it need more time on documentation reading and tool setting.