# Where can I find a yacc grammar for ECMAscript/Actionscript/Javascript

Tags: javascript, actionscript, grammar, yacc

My compilers class requires us to find a yacc grammar for one of these languages and combine it with the tokenizer we wrote. Presumably this is something easy to Google but I can't find it and my classmates are struggling as well. A yacc grammar for any of those three languages would suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grammar at the bellow link uses LALR parser(see [Changelog][1]) same as Yacc, I think is much closer to what you need than ANTLR wich usees LL according to this answer:
[Can a ANTLR grammar file be modified to be used by PLY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988016/can-a-antlr-grammar-file-be-modified-to-be-used-by-ply)

You can find the LALR Ecmascript grammar  here: http://scriptonite.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/scriptonite/scriptonite/src/ecmascript.grammar?revision=1.7